# SQL Server : create trigger to replace old value to new value on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. I want to create a trigger for update which will fire on update of user table.

Trigger functionality: replace `user_tbl` updated mobile number to `user_work_tbl`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_User_Modified]
ON [dbo].[user_tbl]
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @MobileNo varchar(11)

    IF UPDATE (mobile_no) 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @MobileNo VARCHAR(50)

        SELECT @MobileNo = mobile_no 
        FROM [dbo].user_tbl

        UPDATE [dbo].[user_work_tbl]
        SET mobile_no = @MobileNo 
        WHERE [dbo].[user_work_tbl].mobile_no = @oldMobileNo // here I have a problem
    END 
END;
```

In the comment "here I have a problem" I need a mobile number which exists in `user_tbl` before update so that the only row of `user_work_tbl` gets updated.

Any suggestions to do this are also accepted.

Thanks for your all response

Comment: Why are you storing the mobile no in multiple places? By doing so, you're introducing more work for yourself - such as having to write this trigger.

Answer (score 3):

You need to join three tables together in your trigger - `user_work_tbl`, `inserted` and `deleted`. However, its not clear at the moment exactly what conditions are required:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_User_Modified]
ON [dbo].[user_tbl]
AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF UPDATE (mobile_no) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE u
    SET mobile_no=i.mobile_no
    FROM user_work_tbl u
          inner join
         deleted d
          on u.mobile_no = d.mobile_no
          inner join
         inserted i
          on
            i.PKCol = d.PKCol --What's the PK of user_tbl?
END 
END;
```

`inserted` and `deleted` are pseudo-tables that contain the new and old rows that were affected by a particular statement, and have the same schema as the original table. They're only accessible from within the trigger.

Note, also, that the above trigger is correct, even when *multiple* rows are updated in `user_tbl` - provided you can correctly relate `inserted` and `deleted` in the final `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the old phone number from the table **deleted** and the new one from **inserted**, but you should use user primary key the update the rows.

Comment: The `deleted` and `inserted` pseudo tables are **not** in the `dbo` schema - don't use a `dbo.` prefix on them